# regex pattern allowing decimal after 4 digit

Tags: regex

I need help in creating a regex pattern which allows '.' after every 4 digits and length should not be greater than 11. eg.

```
 1234.5678 is valid 
 12345     is invalid
 1234.5678.9 is valid
 1234.5678.91 is invalid as the length of a string is greater than 11
```

Thanks

Comment: *Allows* or *requires*? Is `"1234"` valid? What about `"1234."`?

Comment: http://regex101.com in case you want to try/debug your regex online and post a link here with the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't just *combine* with `|` all (*three* only) possible cases?

```
  ^[0-9]{1,4}$                     - no dot
  ^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,4}$           - one dot
  ^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,2}$ - two dots
```

so the final pattern will be

```
  (^[0-9]{1,4}$)|(^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,4}$)|(^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{1,2}$)
```

In the answer I've *suggested* (since you've not provided the samples) that

1. *Empty string* (`""`) is **not valid**
2. *Short numbers* (e.g. `"123"`, `"1234"`) are **valid**
3. *Dangling dots* (e.g. `"1234."`, `"1234.5678."`) are **invalid**